# Android resizable Toolbar accordingly to scroll on Observable ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, toolbar, telegram

as you can guess from the title I wanted to reproduce the behavior I have seen in apps like Telegram v2.3.2 (Settings activity).
In this paricular case the Toolbar **starts from an initial size and then adjusts its height** (and also scales down the views in it) **down until it reaches the 'normal' height of a common Toolbar** according to the scroll that happens throughout the main content of the activity. How to achieve that?

As i was starting from scratch I've searched the web and found [ManuelPeinado's gist](https://gist.github.com/ManuelPeinado/561748b9fa42d3b25661) which derives from FadingActionBar project, it hosts a View called ObservableScrollView which can monitor for the scroll events. I thought I could resize the toolbar when `onScroll` is called, but I didn't figure out how to achieve the result.

I also found that [Telegram sources](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) are available, which I think it's supercool but they are pretty difficult to read as they are complex, and I can't identify which part of code is responsible for what.

Any advices on how to implement this functionality, or some other resources from the web?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android-ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) is a library which helps build this functionality.

It supports:

- ListView
- ScrollView
- WebView
- RecyclerView
- GridView